# iOS 7 to iOS 6 support

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7, xcode5

I have an app running on iOS 7. Now I want to support is 6+. Here is screenshot on iOS 7.[image: iOS 7 screnshot]

When I changed the deployment target to 6.0, things are positioned strangely on the screen. It shifted everything downward.[image: iOS 6 sacreenshot]

How can I fix it? Do I have to handle the positioning manually according to iOS version?
BTW I am not using auto layout.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so what have you tried?

Comment: Did you try self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: If you are not using `AUTO` layout, you will have to handle it manually...

Comment: Not yet, but i can do it by placing them according to iOS version manually. I wanted to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: @MuhammadNasir `edgesForExtendedLayout` is a iOS7 property. They have it working in iOS 7 and not in iOS 6 so this will not do anything when running on an iOS 6 device.

Answer (score 2):

At least two ways to handle this:

**1.** The big difference here is 0 in the y direction is actually 66px higher on screen in iOS7, by default, since views extends under the navigation bar and status bar.

If you're using storyboards, the simplest fix is to uncheck the 'under top bars' and 'under bottom bars' option when selecting your view controller.

[image: Under top bars and under bottom bars]

However, this isn't the direction Apple's going in iOS7, though.

**2.** You can do the same as #1 by using the [edgesForExtendedLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html) property of your view controller.

**3.** If you're not using autolayout, then you can select your main view and change the iOS6/7 deltas option. In this case, you would want to enter -66 in the delta-Y box and 66 in the delta-height box. These are essentially insets that are applied to views when your app runs on iOS6.

[image: iOS6/7 deltas]

**4.** Use autolayout with appropriate constraints and it should just work. I say should because it's easier to use autolayout if you think of layout in terms of relationships  instead of frames and positions.

Comment: 1 and 2 are not working, 1 makes result like in iOS 6 screenshot.

Comment: But they *are* working since the behavior is now consistent with how it worked on iOS6. Now that the content doesn't go under the nav and status bars, you need to move the content up in the view by 66 pixels and you're all set (unless you want the behavior to vary between the two versions of the OS).

Answer (score 1):

These are basics of iOS 7 UI. You have to read the  transition docs, it's a MUST for iOS developers(you have to login ofcourse) :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174

And you definitely have to watch the WWDC movies, especially:

- building user interfaces for ios 7 (video number 201)
- customizing your app's appearance for ios 7   (video number 214)

You can find them for free in iTunes.

**Regarding you question:**

It is the new iOS 7 approach that causes you issue. In iOS 7, the nav bar is translucent by deafult. In iOS 6 its not. 
In case of translucency - the origin {0,0} is right under the navBar. So if the UIView with such origin in the first case will be under the nav bar, in second case - bellow. You can even notice the new iOS 7 approach of making everything under it nice and blurry - thanks to translucency.

To fix it, use

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

and do the proper code formatting, like changing the origin in different cases.

It is very well explained, and so many more important updates in the docs and the videos that you really should check out, if you want not just to blindly develop, but also understand what are you doing.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, I will take a look at the resource any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup or copy
2. Switch back the "View as" property from 7.0 and later to iOS 6.1 and Earlier.
   [image: File inspector / Interface Builder Document]
   *Beware, all your iOS7 prior settings will be lose after switching back*
3. Rearrange the x coordinate to all subviews because everything will be a bit downer now.
   *(Because in iOS7 the default x=0 coordinates are under the navigation and status bar, and in pre-iOS7 it starts right above the navigation bar or status bar)*
4. At viewDidLoad add the following line:

   ```
   if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Did you Try

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Try

```
 if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
     // here you go with iOS 7
     self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
 }
```

Comment: Yes I tried, It is causing a crash on iOS 6.

Comment: edgesForExtendedLayout is a iOS7 property. They have it working in iOS 7 and not in iOS 6 so this will not do anything when running on an iOS 6 device except cause it to break

Comment: You should use this line instead:
`if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];`

Comment: @TussLászló Yes you would use that instead but the issue isn't iOS7 it works fine in iOS7. They are going backwards they are trying to make it work in iOS6 now. So even that line will not make a difference.

Comment: But it will need for the solution, see my answer